# Python script that will search google in an iterating loop with quotes in the search

Tags: python, google-search

I'm trying to write a python script that will search google in a loop and output the top links. I currently have this:

```
import urllib
import json as m_json

for x in range(3, 5): 
query = 'x mile run'
query = urllib.urlencode ( { 'q' : query } )
response = urllib.urlopen ( 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&' + query ).read()
json = m_json.loads ( response )
results = json [ 'responseData' ] [ 'results' ]
for result in results:
    title = result['title']
    url = result['url']   # was URL in the original and that threw a name error exception
    print ( title + '; ' + url )
```

My problem is modifying the search input to accept double quotes, because I want the script to search a string in a specific website. For example, I want to be able to search: |"#1 Smartest Dog": dogs.com|. And then iterate that 1 after each loop. The combinations of this I've tried have failed terribly, I'm not sure how to make python ignore certain quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to make python ignore a special character add a backslash "\" beforehand:
e.g: "I said "hello"" should be written like this: "I said \"hello\""

Additionally, more specifically. You can also create a multi-line sring using triple quotes """ in which case 1 quote will not end the string. An important piece of information to keep in mind if using this technique is that if you want to end your string with quotation marks you have to put the backslash anyways:

```
myStr = """ This is my string in which I wanted to say:
"hello\""""
```